# Where does Kirito get his new gear?

Tags: sword-art-online

In the beginning of the Sword Art Online anime, episode 2 "Beater", Kirito acquires the *[Coat of Midnight](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Coat_of_Midnight)* when getting the last attack bonus on the boss.

Up until episode 7, "Warmth of the Heart", it appears he is using *mostly* the same gear. In the beginning of this episode when we first see him, he is daunting a new coat and his Elucidator sword. Lizbeth does say, "this is the gnarliest sword you can get from a monster drop" or something to that effect.

Is there ever any mention of where/how he acquired his new gear? I haven't read the manga series, is there any mention in it?

Comment: afaik this isn't covered on how he specifically got the new items before episode 8 but one would assume that it is from boss drops and dungeon treasure chests as shown in the episodes as well as crafting and buying items.

Comment: grind... grind.. grind.. grind.. AND more grind..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Elucidator](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Elucidator) was a drop from "a boss" on the 50th Floor. It's not really specified *which* boss dropped it though, as it could have been the main Floor Boss, a Field Boss, or maybe a boss in a dungeon that happened to be on the 50th Floor. At the time he got it, the sword still had too high of a requirement for him to even wield, but he still consistently upgraded it.

Kirito's coat also changes between most episodes (until they stop changing in Episode 7) and most of his coats are probably either drops, or tailored. However, it's stated that Kirito's final coat, the [Blackwyrm Coat](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Blackwyrm_Coat), was crafted by a player called [Ashley](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Ashley), which was referred to him by Asuna, during the murder mystery story—though that part was cut out of the anime.

Answer (score 2):

Well, maybe it's in the manga or lightnovel, in the anime has no mention of this, but in a RPG is not uncommon to get new gears and weapons, describe all of them and how are acquired takes a lot of time and explanation, and can make a history loses some fun.

Buuuut, here we go:

> The Blackwyrm Coat (ブラックウィルム・コート, Burakku Uirumu Kōto) is a player-made black leather coat, tailored from black dragon leather, a high grade raw material, by Aincrad's best player seamstress, Ashley, that Kirito wore in the final months of Sword Art Online.

Source: http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Blackwyrm_Coat

Comment: Please use `>` block quote tag when copying information from another page to indicate which words are not your own.